# How do I plot time in x axis?

Tags: python, date

when I want plot dates as x axis,ipython usually show:
UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 2: invalid continuation byte.

here is a example:

```
import datetime
import random
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
# make up some data
x = [(datetime.datetime.now() + datetime.timedelta(days=i)).date() for i in range(12)]
y = [i+random.gauss(0,1) for i,_ in enumerate(x)]
# plot
plt.plot(x,y)
# beautify the x-labels
plt.gcf().autofmt_xdate()
plt.show()
```

It will show:UnicodeDecodeError: 'utf8' codec can't decode byte 0xd4 in position 2: invalid continuation byte
How should I fix this problem?My python is 2.7.10,ipython is 3.2.0

Comment: I've just tried to run the example you've given and it plots perfectly with dates on the x-axis (from "Sep 9 2015" to "Sep 19 2015"). What exactly is the problem as I can't recreate it?

Comment: When I change plt.plot(x,y) to plt.plot(range(len(x)),y).It also plots perfectly.so I think it is the problem about dates.